# Motivation for topological categories

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, category-theory, topos-theory

Define a topological category as a small category with topologies on the set of objects $C_0$ and on the set of arrows $C_1$, such that the domain map and the codomain map are continuous.

One can define a classifying topos $\mathcal BC$ of such a category, by taking topological sheaves on $C_0$ with a suitable action of $C_1$ (cfr. Moerdijk, Classifying spaces and classifying topoi).

What I would like to know is why topological categories are so important and what do they add to the context of Grothendieck topologies and Grothendieck sites.

In fact, I have asked elsewhere if, given a topological category $C$, one can build a site of definition for $\mathcal BC$ without already knowing that this latter is a topos. (Because in that case there is always the "Giraud" construction.) But I have obtained no answer.

So what I seek here is a historical contextualization and "qualitative" motivation. Why should one study topological categories in addition to Grothendieck sites?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The paper "In Ehresmann's footsteps: from group geometries to groupoid geometries" J Pradines - arXiv preprint arXiv:0711.1608, 2007 - gives motivation and geometrical background for studying smooth _groupoids_, but does not make a comparison with Grothendieck sites,